# stree command not working after macOS update to Sierra

Tags: macos-sierra, atlassian-sourcetree

My issues is related to:

Updated MacOs to Sierra (10.12.6)

When I type stree command to open sourcetree I get the following error

`stree
objc[11289]: Objective-C garbage collection is no longer supported.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is related to an old source-tree binary not getting updated for some reason. The following steps helped resolve the issue for me.

```
$ rm /usr/local/bin/stree
$ cp /Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/stree /usr/local/bin/stree
$ stree # success
```

Comment: I was not getting an error, but the `stree` command had stopped working. It would open the repository browser, and not the project from which I had entered the command. Using the above fixed this issue for me.